# Integrating youtube-direct-lite with angularjs app

Tags: angularjs, youtube-data-api

I was unable to find any open source video recorder that can be integrated with an angularjs app. I came across [Youtube-direct-lite](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/wiki/HostingYourOwnInstance) but I have no idea how to integrate this with an angular app. I am trying to host my own instance of youtube-direct-lite

I have already configured the config.js as been told in [this](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct-lite/wiki/HostingYourOwnInstance) doc. Should I just copy paste all the js, css files to my project and use the index.html as a partial to display the recorder?

Answer (score 1):

about configuring direct lite:
in config.js enter your developer-key and client-id.
then read the README file
download nodejs console
browse to the folder with the source in it
run this command : node r.js -o app.build.js
and it'll build the minified source for you, then copy and paste that source into your website and use the index.html & admin.html as the 
and i'll work just fine.

about angular with direct lite:
I've seen so far only one implementation for it that is in youtube/dev/demos
http://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/demos.html#/upload
if you opened the sources, you'll find that it is uses angular, and it applies ytdirectlite, but I don't know how to use it and I still cannot find the opensource for it.